# How to plot three related differential equations in Mathematica?

Tags: plotting, differentials, differential-equations

Eq1:

$
\frac{1}{3\phi}=\left[\frac{x}{x+1}\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}+\frac{2x+1}{(x+1)^{2}}\frac{d}{dx}\right]{\phi^{2}}
$

Eq2:

$
\frac{b}{(x+1)^{2}}+\frac{{a}^{\prime}}{x+1}+\frac{b-a}{x(x+1)^{2}}=-\frac{1}{3\phi}+\left[\frac{x}{x+1}\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}+\frac{1}{2(x+1)^{2}}\frac{d}{dx}\right]{\phi^{2}}
$

Eq3:

$
\frac{b}{(x+1)^{2}}+\frac{{b}^{\prime}}{x+1}+\frac{1}{3\phi}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{(x+1)^{2}}\frac{d}{dx}{\phi^{2}}
$

where $a$, $b$ and $\phi$ are functions of $x$.

$a[0]=b[0]=\phi[0]=0$

I tried to plot the first equation alone with condition above using NDSolve but some error appeared

This is what I have done so far:

```
NDSolve[{x/(x + 1) D[\[Phi][x]^2, {x, 2}] + (
     2 x + 1)/(x + 1)^2 D[\[Phi][x], {x, 2}] == 1/(
   3 \[Phi][x]), \[Phi][0] == 0}, \[Phi], {x, 0, 0.02}]
```

But got this error

```
NDSolve::ndnco: The number of constraints (1) (initial conditions) is not equal to the total differential order of the system (2). >>
```

I think I have to include all three equations in NDSolve, but I don't know how to do that

Comment: Artes, I have added demonstrated what I have done so far

Comment: The equation you entered into the `NDSolve` is not equivalent to your   `Eq1`. `Eq1` would be entered as `eq1 = x/(x + 1) D[\[Phi][x]^2, {x, 
      2}] + (2 x + 1)/(x + 1)^2 D[\[Phi][x]^2, x] == 1/(3 \[Phi][x])`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized; i.e, it applies only to the local situation and needs of its poster and answers will not benefit others.